# Split .txt by a certain character using a .bat file

Tags: batch-file

Example: www.website.com|yellow

I would like to be able to remove everything up until the pipe character save out the file and also remove everything after and including the pipe character and save out another file.

Basically trying to split a .txt file into two .txt files by the pipe character using a .bat file.

Comment: Have you googled at all ?

Comment: We're not here to write code for you, but if you genuinely don't know where to start, I'm willing to point you in the right direction. Look at the output of `for /?`, specifically `for /F`. And then read about [redirection](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html).

Answer (score 0):

This solves your question with the data you provided:

```
@echo off
>file.txt echo www.website.com^|yellow
for /f "usebackq tokens=1,* delims=|" %%a in ("file.txt") do (
   >file2.txt echo %%a
   >file3.txt echo ^|%%b
)
pause
```

If you need to do something else then give accurate details about the task.